# Getting one simple Junit test to compile with Gradle on MacOSx

Tags: java, junit, gradle

I'm trying to get the most bare-bones gradle project (with tests) to build. Have looked at all related questions and Google searches, and I seem to be missing something very fundamental, and apparently uncommon.

I created one test class, and "gradle compileTestJava" fails to compile the file saying

> package org.junit does not exist

It finds the test, knows it's a test, but can't seem to find its own junit.jar file.

build.gradle contains

> apply plugin: 'java'

and that is it. Bare bones! I also tried adding

> dependencies {
>
> > testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
>
> }

With that I get "Could not resolve all dependencies" which makes me think gradle has lost its way around its own files(?).  I see gradle's installed /Users/me/Documents/Projects/gradle-1.3/lib/plugins/junit-4.10.jar file.

In fact, when I run "gradle dependencies" I get

```
testCompile - Classpath for compiling the test sources.
No dependencies
```

I have no idea if that is supposed to include built-in plugin dependencies or not. My guess is that it should list junit.

Any ideas?

Here's what I get:

```
:compileTestJava

/Users/me/Documents/Projects/experiment1/src/test/java/MyUnitTests.java:3: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.*;
       ^
/Users/me/Documents/Projects/experiment1/src/test/java/MyUnitTests.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Test
location: class test.java.MyUnitTests
    @Test
     ^
/Users/me/Documents/Projects/experiment1/src/test/java/MyUnitTests.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Assert
location: class test.java.MyUnitTests
            Assert.assertEquals(2 + 2, 4);
            ^
3 errors
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: Did you find solution to this problem? I am stuck here and every solution found did not work so far. I am trying to run unit tests in my android SDK project and facing same problem.

Answer (score 16):

You need to make sure you have your repos set up, and you need to include the dependency for junit. This means that you need something that looks like this for your build.gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
}
```

Comment: For Android Studio, it's `instrumentTestCompile` instead of `testCompile`.

Comment: this still didn't work for me.. had mavenLocal, switched to Central.. no change.

Comment: Note: Here's more information on this topic (towards the end, the author mentions testing a working solution on Gradle versions 2.2 to 2.8): https://softnoise.wordpress.com/2014/09/07/gradle-sub-project-test-dependencies-in-multi-project-builds/

Answer (score 7):

In my build.gradle I had this:

```
android {
sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/test/java'] } }
```

And also

```
dependencies {
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'}
```

The problem went away when I deleted the following from the build.gradle

> 'src/test/java'

Comment: src/test/java gets added automatically to sourceSets when you create that folder with New->Folder->Java Folder. For reference: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTesting/article.html, section 6.2 (see warning).

The reason that it fails is that testCompile only happens for test java files. When it the directory is designated as source, testCompile doesn't happen, and therefore the org.junit package is not compiled in, causing it to fail at runtime.

Comment: As an educational test, you could also add "compile 'junit:junit:4.12'" to your dependencies to see the problem disappear.  Not that you would want to leave it in there for real...

Answer (score 4):

This guide might help -
http://www.slideshare.net/tobiaspreuss/how-to-setup-unit-testing-in-android-studio

Latest gradle the test should be under androidTest dir

Also in your gradle.build:

```
dependencies {
     androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
}
```

also add those under **defaultConfig**

```
defaultConfig {

    testPackageName "test.java.foo"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It might also need mavenLocal()  in your repositories declaration

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar kind of issue on my testcases and got similar kind of error.  I am able to fix it by adding the source sets in my build.gradle file.

For example:

```
sourceSets {
src {
   test{
      java{
    srcDirs =["com/testfile/appservice/test/endpoint"]
    }
      }
}
```

}

src/test/java is the name of the directory just above the test package and com.testfile.appservice.test.endpoint is the name of package where my junit test is written.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

It worked for me, if you are using Android Studio for Android development